# Current Row Wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to get the name I have in the DataGrid In Windows From

Code :
var PersonName = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells [1] .value.ToString ();

But in wpf, this method is not for DataGrid

Comment: WPF isn't winforms. Or there would be no point in it's existence. It's usual to work with bound data in wpf rather than manipulated UI.  A common approach would be to bind an observablecollection of row viewmodels to the itemssource of the datagrid. Bind selecteditem and use a named property from that row viewmodel.

Comment: You need to share what you have tried for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the WPF way. You need to work with the underlying collection that is the `DataSource` of your DataGrid and use the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Show an example 
my data in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to derive the value from the class that `PersonName` came from.  For example, assume you have a `Person` class like this.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

To get the PersonName from the current selected row, you could do something like this:

```
if (myDataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var PersonName = ((Person)myDataGrid.SelectedItem).PersonName;

    // ... now do something with the PersonName
}
```